# Git TFS issues using .dotfiles through Parallels

Tags: git, parallels, team-foundation-server

I'm having an issue with using Git TFS through Parallels with a repository that contains files starting with a dot, vis `.gitignore`.

I'm using Parallels to run a Win8 VM on a Mac. I've got /users/ben/source mapping automatically to Z: in the VM so I can use Git TFS and other Windows trickery on a repo containing a Xamarin solution which I'm working on natively on the Mac.

I get the following when I try to `git tfs checkin`:

```
 add .gitignore
Z:\source\client\project\.git\tfs\default\workspace\.gitignore: No file matches.
Z:\source\client\project\.git\tfs\default\workspace\.gitignore: No file matches.
One item should have been added, but actually added 0 items.
```

The `Z:\source\client\project\.git\tfs\default\workspace\.gitignore` file does actually exist and is visible when I browse to it using the VM's explorer.

I'm thinking that the fact that the dot files are hidden by the Mac and the folder is shared to the VM is causing this grief, as this setup has been working fine before trying to commit the `.gitignore` file. Can anybody verify this and suggest a workaround?

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same message. Same kind of setup: Parallels on OS X, doing Xamarin dev in a Windows VM, project folder is a share from OS X mounted as a network drive in Windows.

Hope someone figures this out soon! Kinda need to be able to use a .gitignore file!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem in the past but not related to a .gitignore file.

running git tfs cleanup seemed to help me out. Try it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I added the .gitignore rules via the Mac Github client. This still creates a .gitignore file in the shared project directory, just as it would in Windows. The file is even visible on Windows side, as you would expect.

BUT, this time, when I execute "git tfs checkintool", it works! I have not yet tried this with a regular checkin command.

So, the real thing I did different is: adding the .gitignore via the Mac side of things. You may not even need to use the Github GUI client to do it, that's just how I did it. Perhaps this is all related to the file forks that OS X uses. Give it a try and mark Accepted if it works for you.